Flask server with picamera2 : 404 not found
Hello I'm new to this part of creating and developing in python and especially for raspberry.
I tried to create a website where I can display a imx519 arducam like a stream.
I found this code on internet but when I run it and go on the page it gives me a 404 error.
here is the code
import io
import picamera2
from flask import Flask, Response

### You can donate at https://www.buymeacoffee.com/mmshilleh if I saved you time
### Subscribe https://www.youtube.com/@mmshilleh/videos

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_frames():
    with picamera2.PiCamera2() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        camera.framerate = 24
        stream = io.BytesIO()

        for _ in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg', use_video_port=True):
            stream.seek(0)
            yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + stream.read() + b'\r\n'
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()

@app.route('/video_feed/')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)

So I already tried to modify the app.route by adding a slash after video_feed but nothing happend.
